# How to get device sim card information using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

There's a library for react-native that can get sim card information but is there other way to get sim card information using Expo?

Library in react-native 
[react-native-sim-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sim-data)

Answer (score 2):

You can use it if you use the `expo eject` command to make `Expo` a stand-alone app. But you can't use it without ejecting `Expo`. Because you have to update your settings on `Android` and `iOS`.

Comment: Is there other way to get device sim info without ejecting from expo?

Comment: Currently, the information that can be obtained is device information using Constants module, without ejecting Expo. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/

Comment: @Michael If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark for my answer?